# "Security" problem with NHibernate on deployed web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, web-applications, deployment

I've deployed to a server a web application that uses NHibernate. The application compiles and runs fine on my local dev machine, but there's an issue with NHibernate on the new server. I get the following error:

> Description: The application attempted
>   to perform an operation not allowed by
>   the security policy.  To grant this
>   application the required permission
>   please contact your system
>   administrator or change the
>   application's trust level in the
>   configuration file.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Security.SecurityException:
>   Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationPermission,
>   System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=tokenkeyhere'
>   failed.

It suggests to change the application's "trust level" in the configuration file. How exactly do I do that? This is the first time I've deployed a NHibernate web app, so I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've been looking at this a lot lately.  Here is a link on [running NHibernate in medium trust](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/run-in-medium-trust.aspx)

This is the most succinct explanation I've seen of the different trust levels: [Trust Levels Demystified](http://codebetter.com/jefferypalermo/2005/07/05/asp-net-trust-levels-demystified-level-300/)

From the article:

```
- Full trust – your code can do anything that the account running it can do.
- High trust – same as above except your code cannot call into unmanaged code. i.e. Win32 APIs, COM interop.
- Medium trust – same as above except your code cannot see any part of the file system except its application directory.
- Low trust – same as above except your code cannot make any out-of-process calls. i.e. calls to a database, network, etc.
- Minimal trust – code is restricted from anything but the most trival processing (calculating algorithms).
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Good to hear - we haven't actually deployed to a medium trust environment yet :)